# Save TableView Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I do make tableview save and load data. I have 2 warning and 2 error.

Errors:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') from 'NSString *__strong'
>   Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
>   Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'id'

Where is my wrong? And How do I fix?

Task.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Task : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL done;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name done:(BOOL)done;

@end
```

Task.m

```
#import "Task.h"

@implementation Task

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize done = _done;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name done:(BOOL)done {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.done = done;
    }
    return self;
}
```

My Save and Load Code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Entering Background");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // paths[0];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
    //NSArray  *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"task", nil];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [_tasks objectEnumerator];
    Task *tempTodo;
    while ( tempTodo = [enumerator nextObject])
    {
        [array addObject:tempTodo.name];
        [array addObject:tempTodo.done]; //Eror is here..
    }
    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:app];


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // paths[0];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] == YES)
    {
        NSMutableArray *readArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        _tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [readArray objectEnumerator];
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
        while ( str = [enumerator nextObject])
        {
            Task *tempTodo = [[Task alloc] init];
            tempTodo.name = str;
            str = [enumerator nextObject];
            tempTodo.done = str;  //Error and warning is here.
            [_tasks addObject:tempTodo]; 

        }
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }

}
```

---

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddTaskSegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *navCon = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddTaskViewController *addTaskViewController = [navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        addTaskViewController.taskListViewController = self;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditDoneTaskSegue"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditNotDoneTaskSegue"]) {
        EditTaskViewController *edit =segue.destinationViewController;
        edit.task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *NotDoneCellIdentifier = @"NotDoneTaskCell";
    static NSString *DoneCellIdentifier = @"DoneTaskCell";

    Task *currentTask = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellIdentifier = currentTask.done ? DoneCellIdentifier : NotDoneCellIdentifier;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = currentTask.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Instead of `@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL done;`</strike>

use

```
@property BOOL done;
```

Also,

```
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
    while ( str = [enumerator nextObject])
    {
        Task *tempTodo = [[Task alloc] init];
        tempTodo.name = str;
        str = [enumerator nextObject];
        tempTodo.done = str;  //Error and warning is here.
```

Here `str` is string and you assigning it to `BOOL`.

And

```
while ( tempTodo = [enumerator nextObject])
{
    [array addObject:tempTodo.name];
    [array addObject:tempTodo.done]; //Eror is here..
}
```

`NSArray` can contain objects only while `tempTodo.done` is `BOOL` which is a primitive type `signed char`

You can box that thing to string or number as

```
[array addObject:@(tempTodo.done)]; //NSNumber
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `@property` line. And in iOS, the default is `atomic` so by removing `nonatomic` you are changing the meaning.

Comment: @rmaddy: OK, i striked those lines.

Comment: tempTodo.done = BOOL; part has error. Eror: Unexpected type name 'BOOL': expected expression

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi:  You need to use either YES or NO. BOOL is a datatype

Comment: Omg. I used yes then All is Done. if yes then yes. if no then no. How do I? My english not good. I hope you understand.

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi: why are you setting `tempTodo.done = YES` and `tempTodo.name = YES`  any use of those? Can you explain me?

Comment: This is a to-do application. name is not YES. name is string. Done is YES or NOT because to-do check or not check. Just i make a simple to-do application. For learn objective-c.

Comment: Yes, name is string, sorry for that. But you are assigning `NSString *str` to `tempTodo.done = str;` this is wrong. What logic you wanted to implement.

Comment: I found this code on the internet. I upload my project, could you help me?

Comment: tomorw morning i am going on leave for 2 days, no mac with me, so i cant help you.

Comment: What can I do now? How I fixed?

Comment: I added some code. Can you please check? I am not receiving any error but not exactly at the moment does not work.